# Images only are disappearing on mobile devices but rest of content visible

Tags: css

Images only in this particular row of my webpage are disappearing when displayed on the iPad mini (768x1024) and the Galaxy Tablet (800x1280). Other content in the section remain visible. Why would this be happening? Is there a quirk with the mobile devices or perhaps an error in my CSS? (On the rest of the page both images and text are displaying properly on mobile devices.)

The (barebones) code for the row is:

```
<div class="row" id="advertcontainer">
    <h2 class="wow fadeInUp adjust" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="max-width: 100%;display: block;">What's On across the Lakeside Group</h2>
    <div class="grid_4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
        <div class="imagediv">
            <a href=""><img src="image.jpg" alt="image test" />
            <div class="transparent_ribbon"></div>
            <div class="overlayeventname">Text here</div>
            <div class="overlayeventplace">More text here</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /row /advertcontainer -->
```

In my CSS I've set a breakpoint of 768 to hide this entire row:

```
 @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #advertcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

My complete stylesheet can be viewed at http://www.lakesidesurrey.co.uk/css/style.css

This is what it should look like [image]
But this is what is being displayed on the iPad mini and the Galaxy Tablet
[image]

Comment: `@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #advertcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
  .imagediv {
    max-width: 370px;
    max-height: 254px;
}
}
`

Why would you set `height` & `width` to the image if the whole container is `display:none`?

Comment: I cant seem to find the problem, but could you try to check if it works or not without the effects of animation wow and if you use any JS jquery on it?

Comment: When I remove wow, the images disappear across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have this rule in your CSS:

```
.imagediv img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This will move those images *behind* all regular layers and change their position to the upper left corner of their containers (if they have `position: relative`). If those parent elements are not transparent, the images will remain invisible.

Plus, if the image size isn't set within the `img` tag, the size will be 0x0 since there is no defined `width`and `height` --> they'll be invisible...

Comment: Yes, the absolute position is to place the image behind the overlay and text and that works. The regular layer are relative from the upper left corner and those work. Even with the image width and height set, the images still disappear on all mobile devices.